# Converting my apps mysql to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been recently made aware that mysql ext is being removed in pHP in the future and so i have to convert to mysqli or PDO ext…

It seems like converting to PDO will be easier and so I am first trying that.  I have a simple mysql app here that I am trying to convert to PDO; here it is:

```
$hostname='localhost';
$username='user11111';
$password='gpassword1';
$dbname='gman_school_db';
$usertable='your_tablename';
$yourfield = 'your_field';

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", "$username", "$password");

$sql = "INSERT INTO members (user_id, user_name, email)
VALUES (680, 'GMAN678BABY333333', 'email_ok_man')";

mysql_query($sql);

$db = null;
```

I pieced this together finding some conversion code but it is not working, I do not know if my connect stuff is wrong in some way or if my "insert statement" cannot work with this PDO connection; so I am hoping someone can tell me what is wrong with this…

Thanks!

*********UPDATED ATTEMPT 2:22am EST *****************

here is my attempt using info from both Fred and Hankypanky:

```
/* Connect to a mysql database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=gman_db1;host=localhost';
$user = 'gman_user1';
$password = 'gman54678';

try {
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */

$user_id=699;
$user_name="wayne_sax";
$email="wayne@saxman.com";

$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO members (user_id, user_name,  email) VALUES (:user_id, :user_name, :email)');

$sth->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
```

I am not getting any errors when I run it; but it does not insert the record properly so something is not right; so if anyone can see anything wrong with this please let me know…

All the best,  G

****** update 3:34am set *******
using hanky pankys code - I got the following errors:

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the  manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near   'INSERTÂ INTOÂ membersÂ (user_id,Â user_name, email)Â VALUESÂ (699,Â' at line 1 )
```

I also ran Meda's suggestion below and it got a "fatal error" on the execute statement; which makes me think it is connecting OK;

so it looks like my insert statement is messed up; i know how to do it in mysql; looking at this trying to see what is wrong...

Comment: Those two APIs do not mix, so this `mysql_query($sql);` should not be in there. Read up on [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: You're also missing a few parts, so check the link I've given you above. One of which being `execute()`. Doing it the way you have now, still leaves you open to [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/), so use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks Fred, please see my update above; tried to use your info and Hankypanky's info but still not working, so if you are willing maybe you can look at it and see if you can find anything wrong?

Comment: @gman_donster You state in a comment you're connecting to an ODBC database, yet your driver listed is for mysql.

Comment: thanks daedalus; i just copied it from what hanky-panky had below; and it had that comment on it; but to clear up any confusion i edited the comment; but if you have any other input I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example taken straight from [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). Which part of it do you not understand specifically?

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

Obviously that assumes you have created a PDO object first, but even that can be seen on the **[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)**.

```
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Hankypanky, please see my update above; tried to use your info and Fred's info but still not working, so if you are willing maybe you can look at it and see if you can find anything wrong?

Comment: After your `execute` call, can you see `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` and `print_r($sth->errorInfo());` And see what they say?

Comment: Thanks Hanky Panky:  I will paste in the errors from your code above; give me a second...

Comment: OK - I added the error statements into my question above; looks like it is connecting ok but there is a problem with my mysql insert statement...

Comment: Notice this `INSERTÂ INTOÂ membersÂ`; it means your statement has unwanted special characters in it even though you don't see them. Please retype the whole SQL statement like you see it and those will be removed

Answer (score 1):

It sound to me like you are not able to get the errors try connecting like this:

```
try {
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, 
                 array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

This way you will find out about the error.

Comment: thanks Media; I did that and it gave me a "fatal error" on the execute statement; which makes me think it is connecting ok…i also tried hanky-panky's stuff above and that gave me other info...

Comment: @gman_donster when you use `bindParam` you also limited the input to 12, this might give you unexpected result

Comment: Thanks Meda, I changed the 12 on both of them to 100 but that made no difference; you can see the error messages I got from some other code up in my question…  thanks, G

Comment: It complains about the variable `$user_name` does it have anything different